# Getting data from select with inner join on same mysql table

Tags: mysql

This is my cases table

```
id empid    reaction         date_t
1  emp109   interested       2017-09-12
2  emp109   not_interested   2017-09-13
3  emp109   maybe            2017-09-13
```

What I am trying to achieve is for particular employee id

```
date_t  | number of interested  |number of not interested   | number of maybe
```

Like on 2017-09-12 and 2017-09-13 for employee id emp109 the table will look something like this

```
 date_t     | number of interested  |number of not interested   | maybe
 2017-09-12    1                        0                        0
 2017-09-13    0                       1                         1
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT cases.date_t, cases.empid,COUNT(cases.reaction) as interested  FROM `cases` WHERE cases.reaction="interested" and cases.empid="EMP12654"  GROUP by cases.date_t)alpha
JOIN
(SELECT cases.date_t, cases.empid,COUNT(cases.reaction) as not_interested  FROM `cases` WHERE cases.reaction="not_interested" and cases.empid="EMP12654"  GROUP by cases.date_t)beta
on alpha.date_t=beta.date_t
JOIN
(SELECT cases.date_t, cases.empid,COUNT(cases.reaction) as maybe  FROM `cases` WHERE cases.reaction="maybe" and cases.empid="EMP12654"  GROUP by cases.date_t)zeta
on alpha.date_t=zeta.date_t
```

This is not giving me the desired result any idea how to achieve it??

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called pivoting.

You can do this in MySQL using conditional aggregation:

```
select date_t,
    sum(reaction = 'interested') as interested,
    sum(reaction = 'not_interested') as not_interested,
    sum(reaction = 'maybe') as maybe
from your_table
group by date_t;
```

The above uses the fact that MySQL treats true as 1 and false as 0.

Comment: Cool ,that worked !! thanks for telling me something new ,Cheere :)